# Facebook like/recommend button on facebook iFrame tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to add a like/recommend button to a facebook tab.An example of facebook tab is [this](http://www.facebook.com/nike/app_265092000187882).

The problem with using facebook like/recommend is that if we have done fan gating and the user has to like the page before he/she can view the content of the tab, then the like/recommend will always be greyed out, since the page has been liked.

So in particular I want the user to like a section of the page not the complete page.

I have gone through the net and found out some hacks for it like [this](http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/how-to-add-a-like-button-to-your-facebook-tabs/) and [this](http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-add-a-like-button-to-your-facebook-static-fbml-tab/). 
I don't want to use [fb:comments](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments/) or [fb:share](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) as they have been deprecated. Is there any other way around.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to achieve? Why would you want the user to like a section of the page, as opposed to the entire page? What about using the Comments Plugin: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Answer (score 0):

Place this code inside your page:
You need to specify data-href to your particular link.
Leaving it empty gets facebook to like the current page.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```